# Who owned each heirloom?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

At the dinner party were Lady Winslow, Doctor Marcolla, Countess Contee, Madam Natsiou and Baroness Finch.

The women sat in a row. They all wore different colors and Doctor Marcolla wore a jaunty purple hat. Lady Winslow was at the far left, next to the guest wearing a green jacket. The lady in red sat left of someone in white. I remember that red outfit because the woman spilled her absinthe all over it. The traveler from Dabovka was dressed entirely in blue. When one of the dinner guests bragged about her Snuff Tin, the woman next to her said they were finer in Dabovka, where she lived.

So Baroness Finch showed off a prized Diamond, at which the lady from Dunwall scoffed, saying it was no match for her Bird Pendant. Someone else carried a valuable Ring, and when she saw it, the visitor from Fraeport next to her almost spilled her neighbor's whiskey. Madam Natsiou raised her wine in toast. The lady from Karnaca, full of beer, jumped up onto the table, falling onto the guest in the center seat, spilling the poor woman's rum. Then Countess Contee captivated them all with a story about her wild youth in Baleton.

In the morning, there were four heirlooms under the table: the Snuff Tin, War Medal, the Bird Pendant, and the Ring.

But who owned each?

Comment: Question: is the "neighbor" with the whiskey the same neighbour who showed the Ring, or could they be two ladies on either side of she from Fraeport?

Comment: Did the lady in red sit *immediately* left of the one in white?  (Or is the puzzle solvable without knowing?)

Comment: @puzzledPig The lady in red sat immediately next to the one in white.

Comment: @Randal'Thor She doesn't necessarily have to be the same one who showed the ring.

Comment: It is probably a good thing to specify that this puzzle ("Jindosh's Puzzle") comes from the acclaimed videogame *Dishonored 2*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we know:

- "Lady Winslow was at the far left"

  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?|?|?|?
  >   color    |?      |?|?|?|?
  >   drink    |?      |?|?|?|?
  >   origin   |?      |?|?|?|?
  >   item     |?      |?|?|?|?
  > ```
- "next to the guest wearing a green jacket"

  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?    |?|?|?
  >   color    |?      |green|?|?|?
  >   drink    |?      |?    |?|?|?
  >   origin   |?      |?    |?|?|?
  >   item     |?      |?    |?|?|?
  > ```
- "falling onto the guest in the center seat, spilling the poor woman's rum."

  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?    |?  |?|?
  >   color    |?      |green|?  |?|?
  >   drink    |?      |?    |rum|?|?
  >   origin   |?      |?    |?  |?|?
  >   item     |?      |?    |?  |?|?
  > ```
- "The lady in red sat left of someone in white. I remember that red outfit because the woman spilled her absinthe all over it."

  > As the lady in red is sat left to someone in white, we need two empty colors next to each others, so column 3-4 or 4-5. As the woman in red spilled her absinthe, it can't be column 3.
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?    |?  |?       |?
  >   color    |?      |green|?  |red     |white
  >   drink    |?      |?    |rum|absinthe|?
  >   origin   |?      |?    |?  |?       |?
  >   item     |?      |?    |?  |?       |?
  > ```
- " Doctor Marcolla wore a jaunty purple hat. "

  > only two empty colors, but the first column have already a name
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?    |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |?      |green|purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |?      |?    |rum     |absinthe|?
  >   origin   |?      |?    |?       |?       |?
  >   item     |?      |?    |?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "traveler from Dabovka was dressed entirely in blue"
  only one empty color, so we have all colors

  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?    |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green|purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |?      |?    |rum     |absinthe|?
  >   origin   |Dabovka|?    |?       |?       |?
  >   item     |?      |?    |?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "When one of the dinner guests bragged about her Snuff Tin, the woman next to her said they were finer in Dabovka, where she lived."

  > we got our first item
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?        |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |?      |?        |rum     |absinthe|?
  >   origin   |Dabovka|?        |?       |?       |?
  >   item     |?      |Snuff Tin|?       |?       |?
  > ```
  >
  > there are three alcohol left: wine, beer, whiskey
- "Madam Natsiou raised her wine in toast. The lady from Karnaca, full of beer, jumped up onto the table, falling onto the guest in the center seat, spilling the poor woman's rum."

  > Natsiou have wine, lady from Karnace have beer, therefore whiskey is in first column
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?        |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|?        |rum     |absinthe|?
  >   origin   |Dabovka|         |?       |?       |?
  >   item     |?      |Snuff Tin|?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "Someone else carried a valuable Ring, and when she saw it, the visitor from Fraeport next to her almost spilled her neighbor's whiskey. "

  > ring bearer drink whiskey and is sat next to visitor from Fraeport
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?        |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|?        |rum     |absinthe|?
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |?       |?       |?
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "The lady from Karnaca, full of beer"

  > the only column with drink and origin empty is the fitfth column
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|?        |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|?        |rum     |absinthe|beer
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |?       |?       |Karnaca
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "Madam Natsiou raised her wine in toast."

  > There is only one person left without drink. we also got his name
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|Natsiou  |Marcolla|?       |?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red     |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|whine    |rum     |absinthe|beer
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |?       |?       |Karnaca
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|?       |?       |?
  > ```
- "Then Countess Contee captivated them all with a story about her wild youth in Baleton."

  > We need an empty name and empty origin. 4th column
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|Natsiou  |Marcolla|Countess Contee|?
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red            |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|wine     |rum     |absinthe       |beer
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |?       |Baleton        |Karnaca
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|?       |?              |?
  > ```
- "So Baroness Finch showed off a prized Diamond"

  > We got the last name, and his item
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|Natsiou  |Marcolla|Countess Contee|Baroness Finch
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple  |red            |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|wine     |rum     |absinthe       |beer
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |?       |Baleton        |Karnaca
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|?       |?              |Diamond
  > ```
- ", at which the lady from Dunwall scoffed, saying it was no match for her Bird Pendant"

  > We got the last origin, and his item
  >
  > ```
  >   character|Winslow|Natsiou  |Marcolla    |Countess Contee|Baroness Finch
  >   color    |blue   |green    |purple      |red            |white
  >   drink    |whiskey|wine     |rum         |absinthe       |beer
  >   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |Dunwall     |Baleton        |Karnaca
  >   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|Bird Pendant|?              |Diamond
  > ```
- "In the morning, there were four heirlooms under the table: the Snuff Tin, War Medal, the Bird Pendant, and the Ring."

> By elimination, the last item is War Medal
>
> ```
>   character|Winslow|Natsiou  |Marcolla    |Countess Contee|Baroness Finch
>   color    |blue   |green    |purple      |red            |white
>   drink    |whiskey|wine     |rum         |absinthe       |beer
>   origin   |Dabovka|Fraeport |Dunwall     |Baleton        |Karnaca
>   item     |Ring   |Snuff Tin|Bird Pendant|War Medal      |Diamond
> ```

Answer (score 3):

### Puzzle setup

- There are five women: **W, M, C, N, F.**
- Wearing five colours: purple, green, red, white, blue.
- From five locations: Dobovka, Dunwall, Fraeport, Karnaca, Baleton.
- Drinking five different tipples: absinthe, whiskey, beer, rum, wine.
- With five heirlooms: **ST, WM, BP, R, D.**

Condensing the information given in the question:

1. M = purple.
2. W in 1st seat.
3. Green in 2nd seat.
4. Red left of white.
5. Red = absinthe.
6. Dabovka = blue.
7. Snuff Tin next to Dabovka.
8. F = Diamond.
9. Dunwall = Bird Pendant.
10. Ring next to Fraeport.
11. Fraeport next to whiskey (not sure if whiskey = ring?)
12. N = wine.
13. Karnaca = beer.
14. Rum in 3rd seat.
15. C = Baleton.

### Deductions

*(Here I'm assuming red must be **immediately** next to white; the puzzle statement isn't quite clear.)*

From clues **3** and **4**, red and white must be in the 3rd and 4th or 4th and 5th seats. From clues **1** and **2**, purple is not in the 1st seat. So

> blue is in the 1st seat, green in the 2nd.

Also by clues **5** and **14**, red can't be in the 3rd seat. So

> purple is in the 3rd seat, red in the 4th seat, white in the 5th seat. Also rum is in the 3rd seat and absinthe in the 4th seat.

By clues **6** and **7**,

> Dabovka is in the 1st seat and Snuff Tin in the 2nd seat.

By clues **1** and **2** again,

> W is in the 1st seat and M in the 3rd seat.

By clues **12** and **13**, the ladies (N = wine) and (Karnaca = beer) both must be

> in either the 2nd or 5th seats (not 3rd or 4th because rum and absinthe, not 1st because W and Dabovka). These two ladies also can't be the same, so they *must* occupy those two seats in some order. By elimination, whiskey is in the 1st seat.

Now by clue **11**,

> Fraeport is in the 2nd seat. This means (N = wine) is in the 2nd seat and (Karnaca = beer) is in the 5th seat.

By clue **15**, the lady (C = Baleton) must be

> in the 4th seat (not 1st, 2nd, 3rd because W, N, M, not 5th because Karnaca).

By elimination, Dunwall is

> in the 3rd seat, so by clue **9**, Bird Pendant is in the 3rd seat. By clue **10**, Ring is in the 1st seat.

Finally, by clue **8**, the lady (F = Diamond) must be

> in the 5th seat (not 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th because W, N, M, C), so the War Medal is in the 4th seat.

### The solution

1. > On the left is Lady Winslow from Dabovka, wearing blue, drinking whiskey, with a Ring.
2. > Next is Madam Natsiou from Fraeport, wearing green, drinking wine, with a Snuff Tin.
3. > Next is Doctor Marcolla from Dunwall, wearing purple, drinking rum, with a Bird Pendant.
4. > Next is Countess Contee from Baleton, wearing red, drinking absinthe, with a War Medal.
5. > On the right is Baroness Finch from Karnaca, wearing white, drinking beer, with a Diamond.